# Angular.js default filtering

Tags: angularjs

i have a simple page with a table and a select. I need to apply a filtering with a default value preselected in the html select. The filter need to be applied immediately, when the page finish the loading phase . Here's my code:

The select:

```
<select class="span2" ng-model="fiASS">
        <option></option>
        <option>Ftse Mib</option>
        <option ng-selected="selected">Nasdaq</option>
        <option>Dow Jones</option>
        <option>Dax</option>
        <option>Cac40</option>
    </select>
```

The repeater and filters

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in titoliASS | filter:filtroASS | filter:exchange| filter:poASS | orderBy:predicateASS:reverseASS">
            <td>{{obj.TITOLO}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.INDICE}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.POSIZIONE}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.PREZZO}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.S1}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.R1}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.S2}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">{{obj.R2}}</td>
            <td><a href="Technical_Analysis.html?idtitolo={{obj.ID}}&titolo={{obj.TITOLO}}"><i class='icon-signal xmlcursor'></i></a></td>
        </tr>
```

The preselection for a default value in the select works but the filter is not applied.
The filter is applied only when i change value on the select.
I hope the prob is clear.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems. First, your `ng-selected` expression doesn't match your match your model.

Second, even if it did, it won't pick it up from the html; the `fiASS` variable would need to be set on the scope in your controller.

Assuming, however, that the data for the `select` is static, you could just encode it in your controller instead of the HTML and use `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model='fiASS' ng-options='index for index in indices'></select>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.fiASS = 'Nasdaq';
$scope.indices = ['Ftse Mib', 'Nasdaq', 'Dow Jones', 'Dax', 'Cac40'];
```

This would set up the models correctly once the code is loaded, and your filters (assuming they rely on the value of `fiASS`) should be applied.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f49Fy/).